# Grouping binary dataframe in R by category

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

My dataframe `df` currently looks like this:

```
  cat 1 2 3 4
1 a   0 1 0 1
2 b   0 0 1 0 
3 b   1 0 1 1 
4 a   1 0 1 1
5 b   1 1 1 1
6 a   0 1 1 0

cat <- c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a")
df = cbind(cat, data.frame(matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0), nrow=6, byrow = T)))
```

(i.e. 2 categories in the first column, and binary data for each category in each subsequent column). Ideally, I would like to group each column by category, but also by binary category, ending up with something like:

```
1 a.0 2 1 1 1
2 a.1 1 2 2 2
3 b.0 0 1 0 1
4 b.1 2 1 2 2
```

My best attempt so far is:

```
aggregate(df[,-1], by=list(df[,1]), FUN = table)
```

but this doesn't give me exactly what I'm after unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -cat) %>%
  mutate(new_cat=paste(cat, value, sep="_")) %>%
  group_by(new_cat, key) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(key, n) %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)
```

Output is:

```
  new_cat    X1    X2    X3    X4
1     a_0     2     1     1     1
2     a_1     1     2     2     2
3     b_0     1     2     0     1
4     b_1     2     1     3     2
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(cat = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a"), X1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X3 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X4 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("cat", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count each binary category in the data frame in the following way:

```
df[df$cat == "a", -1]  == 1
```

This example was from a, and 1. That command will return the following table:

```
     X1    X2    X3    X4
1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
4  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
6 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now, you can just apply, by column, a sum to that function to get one of the rows. In this case it returns the row a.1 of your dataframe:

```
apply(df[df$cat == "a", -1]  == 1, 2, sum)
```

Similarly, you can find the other remainings rows.

```
apply(df[df$cat == "a", -1]  == 0, 2, sum)
apply(df[df$cat == "a", -1]  == 1, 2, sum)
apply(df[df$cat == "b", -1]  == 0, 2, sum)
apply(df[df$cat == "b", -1]  == 1, 2, sum)
```

If you really need to repeat this operation, one might build an iterative function where at each iteration you change the value of interest based on the values of cat, i.e.

```
for (val in levels(df$cat)) apply(df[df$cat == val, -1]  == 1, 2, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- structure(list(cat = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a"), X1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X3 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X4 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("cat", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df <- split(df, df$cat) # Split by Cat
df <- lapply(seq_along(df),function(i) 
      {
        kk<- apply(df[[i]],2,table) # Find frequency in each column 
        kk <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, kk)) # Combine list by column 
        kk$cat <- paste(names(df)[i],rownames(kk), sep = ".") # Define name of cat column 
        rownames(kk)<- NULL
        kk
      })
n_df <- do.call(rbind, df) # Combine list by row
```